# php email is not getting send

Tags: php

I am just wondering if anybody sees any error here, the code executes but I never get the email, any suggestions?

```
$to = $_POST['to_email'];
$subject = $_POST['subject'];
$message='<p><b>Message:</b> '.str_replace("\n.", "\n..", $_POST['message']).'</p>';

$headers = "From: " . strip_tags($_POST['from_email']) . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: ". strip_tags($_POST['from_email']) . "\r\n".
        'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

Comment: check your /var/log/mail.log or /var/log/syslog files. May be your mta gives you more info.

Comment: Have you tried using sendmail (or whatever mta you have installed) directly? It is possible that your system has a misconfigured/missing MTA.

Comment: **Warning!**  Your code contains an email header injection vulnerability.  Removing HTML isn't enough.  Please use a modern email handler like [SwiftMailer](http://swiftmailer.org) or [PHPMailer](http://phpmailer.worxware.com).

Comment: possible duplicate of [simple php mail not sending email](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6461714/simple-php-mail-not-sending-email)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will depend on the setup of PHP.

There are a number of things PHP can do - the most common are queue the email to a local mail server (common on linux, less so on windows) or talk to an external mail relay and queue the mail there (usually requires authentication unless it's an open relay which is rare). It's also possible to write to file.

All that the `mail()` function guarantees if there are no warnings is that the email has been queued to the location specified in the php.ini file.

The first thing to do is check that mail is reporting success...

```
$Success = @mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
if(!$Success) {
    print "Failed to queue email";
}
```

The next thing you need to do is check your `php.ini` config to see how email is configured. Make sure it points at a valid mail server with the correct credentials. If you're on linux and using a local mail server like [postfix](http://www.postfix.org/), check that it's running (something like `/etc/init.d/postfix status` depending on your distro)

As mentioned by @FlorianKasper, SMTP as an option is only available on Windows. If you can clarify exactly what OS you're using, we may be able to help further.

Comment: the php ini sais for the SMTP: ;Windows only so on unix based systems you must use the sendmail/something simmilar command
http://php.net/manual/de/mail.configuration.php#ini.smtp

Comment: That's true but I don't see that it makes my answer incorrect? The OP hasn't specified OS and it's also possible to use a local mail server on windows if you install one eg [xmailserver](http://www.xmailserver.org/)

Comment: Not at all :) I always welcome additional information and I'll add it to my answer, thank you. Apologies if I sounded defensive

Answer (score 1):

mail() function just uses the sendmail unix/linux command to send mails. If it is wrong configured it won't work

If you have access to your php ini check out the [mail] section

```
smtp = SMTPSERVER (windows)
smtp_port = 25    (Windows)
sendmail_path= (unix)
```