# Submit form with ajax problems

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am having issues with this message form submission. I can get the information to send to the .php file but the email is not sending can anyone help me?

here is the jquery

```
$('form.contact').on('submit', function() {

  var that    = $(this),
      url     = that.attr('action'),
      type  = that.attr('method'),
      data    = {};

  that.find('[name]').each(function() {
      var that = $(this);
          name = that.attr('name');
          value = that.val();

      data[name] = value;
  });

  $.ajax({
      url: url,
      type: type,
      data: data,
      success: function(response) {
        console.log(response);
      }
  });

  return false;
});
```

and here is the php

```
include 'config.php';

// Email Submit
if (isset($_POST['email']) && isset($_POST['name']) && isset($_POST['message'])){

   //send email
   mail(EMAIL_ADDRESS, "Contact Form: ".$_POST['name'],
   $_POST['message'], "From:" . $_POST['email']);

}
```

`EMAIL_ADDRESS` is a constant that is set by the admin.

and if needed here is the html

```
<div id="contact_form">
    <form action="admin/submit.php" method="post" class="contact">
        <input class="fullwidth" type="text" name="name" placeholder="Your Name" />
        <input class="fullwidth" type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email Address" />
        <textarea type="text" name="message" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
        <input id="submit" type="submit" value="Submit" />
        <div id="submit_triangle"></div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you get any errors? Is there a reason you set `that` twice to different `$(this)`? Could cause trouble I assume..

Comment: Can you verify that you can send *any* mail from your server? This may not be a jQuery issue.

Comment: @mg007 how do I check that?

Comment: There's definitely a jQuery issue. Check my answer.

Comment: @Maresh the console log gives me all of the fields and the content inside them as an associative array

Comment: @Maresh - your answer is wrong, val() works fine with a textarea.

Comment: @zachstarnes - You know that doing just doing `$(this).serialize()` would do the exact same thing as you are doing when creating the object ?

Comment: @zachstarnes You can use a one-liner to check if you can send a mail. Check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6461777/155813).

Comment: @adeneo: Ok, I remembered it didn't though. my bad.

Comment: _"... email is not sending..."_ - What does this mean? What error are you getting? Have you set up a mail server which can send mails?

Comment: @ShuklaSannidhya it worked after I created a mail account on the server. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Well, your code seems to be fine. But do you have a mail server installed on the system. Check the settings of the mail server if you have it

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php says that the `mail` returns TRUE if the mail was successfully accepted for delivery, FALSE otherwise.

It is important to note that just because the mail was accepted for delivery, it does NOT mean the mail will actually reach the intended destination

Answer (score 0):

If you were able to send data to .php, then it has to be php side that you are having difficulty.  Turn on your error handler via php.ini and it should tell you what is the php issue you are having.

In your php file with email functions in it, add these lines in the very beginning of the script:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL); 
ini_set('display_errors', true);

//your exiting script //
?>
```

Then re-run the script, and if it still doesn't work, php should echo the php issue for you to debug.

Comment: This does not solve OP's problem. You should have added it as a comment.

Comment: @ShuklaSannidhya:  Thanks. I stand corrected, this should be entered as comment, not answer.

Comment: @Faron it does not give me an error if i do the single line test on a separate file